# Which is version is in demand right now?

Tags: angularjs, angular, jobs

I want to learn AngularJS, but I'm not sure what version should I start at? Also, what version of AngularJS is being used by today's companies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 4 is [now](http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2017/03/angular-400-now-available.html) available (since end of March 2017).

The main thing to know is that angular 1.* is not backward compatible with angular 2.* or 4.* (they skipped version 3.*)

Angular 2.0 introduced breaking changes in order to redesign the way Angular was working.Angular 4.0 is backward compatible with Angular 2.0

In the industry today, you will find a mix of Angular 1.* and other versions.

If you're starting it is better to learn the latest one (Angularjs 4.0) as in the near future everyone will have migrated to the latest version of Angularjs and the jobs remainig in Angularjs 1.* will be for legacy system only.

You can have a look [here](http://angularjs.blogspot.co.uk/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html) for more info